# How to get only one value when you are getting multiple values against key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query. Below is the query

```
select 
    ID, 
    replace(replace(replace(replace([Name],',',''),'"',''),':',''),'?','') [Name] ,
    replace(replace([Description],',',''),'"','') [Description],
    [GUID],
    Bussinesskey 
from course 
where COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and RETIREDTF = 0  
and 
    bussinesskey in 
    (
    ...
    )
and id in (
    select c.id from course c
    inner join COURSE_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cce on cce.COURSE_ID = c.ID
    inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
    where 
        ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'Course' 
    and ce.customer_id =  23753 
    and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
    UNION 
    select c.id from course c
    inner join COURSE_COURSEGROUP cg on cg.course_id = c.id
    inner join COURSEGROUP_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cgce on cgce.COURSEGROUP_ID = cg.COURSEGROUP_ID
    inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cgce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
    where 
        ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'CourseGroup' 
    and ce.customer_id = 23753  
    and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
)
order by name, id asc
```

When this query runs then I get the output like the following snapshot

[image: Query Screen shot]

You can see in the screen shot that I am getting `8 names of same type(Contracts)`. The last `id` of `Contracts` is `780697` which is the latest record that is added to database. Now i want that when my query runs then it gets only the latest record. Means instead of showing `8 name of Contarcts`. Its only the show the latest one for each course name. Means for Contracts only record with ID `780697` is shown. If other courses has the same result then there latest Id record is shown only. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your DB design makes this confusion. You'd probably be best off with a review and rebuild. However; your questions backwards: How to get a Max(Key) per field value. So, if you took your query in a CTE, and created a second CTE getting max ID per name, and join the two CTEs youd be getting max(ID) per course name as a filter, and all the data from the first CTE for that max(id)...

Answer (score 1):

You can try following for achieving latest ID:-

```
select MAX(ID), 
replace(replace(replace(replace([Name],',',''),'"',''),':',''),'?','') [Name] ,
replace(replace([Description],',',''),'"','') [Description],
[GUID],
Bussinesskey 
from course 
where COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and RETIREDTF = 0  
and 
bussinesskey in 
(
...
)
and id in (
select c.id from course c
inner join COURSE_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cce on cce.COURSE_ID = c.ID
inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
where 
    ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'Course' 
and ce.customer_id =  23753 
and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
UNION 
select c.id from course c
inner join COURSE_COURSEGROUP cg on cg.course_id = c.id
inner join COURSEGROUP_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cgce on cgce.COURSEGROUP_ID = cg.COURSEGROUP_ID
inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cgce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
where 
    ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'CourseGroup' 
and ce.customer_id = 23753  
and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
)
group by [Name], [Description], [GUID], Bussinesskey 
order by name, id asc
```

Comment: Grouping by GUID and Business will not result in a single row for Contracts as described by OP

Comment: Yup running this query is generating error that `Column "course.ID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score 0):

```
    ;with Course as
    (
        Select 50000 ID, 'Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB1' BusinessKey
            UNION
        Select 60000 ID, 'Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB2' BusinessKey
            UNION
        Select 70000 ID, 'Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB3' BusinessKey
            UNION
        Select 80000 ID, 'Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB4' BusinessKey
            UNION
        Select 90000 ID, 'Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB5' BusinessKey
            UNION
        Select 40000 ID, 'NOT Contracts' Name, '<BLURB>' [Description], '<GUID>' GUID, 'ARB1' BusinessKey
    ),
    Course_Group AS 
    (
        Select 50000 Course_ID, 1 COURSEGROUP_ID 
            UNION
        Select 60000 Course_ID, 1 COURSEGROUP_ID 
            UNION
        Select 70000 Course_ID, 1 COURSEGROUP_ID 
            UNION
        Select 80000 Course_ID, 1 COURSEGROUP_ID 
            UNION
        Select 90000 Course_ID, 2 COURSEGROUP_ID 
            UNION
        Select 40000 Course_ID, 1 COURSEGROUP_ID 
    ),
    CourseGroup_CustomerEntitlement AS
    (
        Select 1 COURSEGROUP_ID, 1 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
        --UNION
        --Select 2 COURSEGROUP_ID, 2 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
        --UNION
        --Select 2 COURSEGROUP_ID, 4 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
    ),
    Course_CustomerEntitlement AS
    (
        Select 50000 Course_ID, 3 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
            UNION
        Select 60000 Course_ID, 3 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
            UNION
        Select 90000 Course_ID, 3 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
            UNION
        Select 40000 Course_ID, 4 CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
    ),
    CustomerEntitlement AS
    (
        Select 1 ID, 23753 Customer_ID, 'CourseGroup' ENROLLMENTTYPE
        UNION
        Select 2 ID, 7 Customer_ID, 'NOT COURSE GROUP' ENROLLMENTTYPE
        UNION
        Select 3 ID, 23753 Customer_ID, 'Course' ENROLLMENTTYPE
        UNION
        Select 4 ID, 7 Customer_ID, 'NOT COURSE' ENROLLMENTTYPE
    ),
    CTE_base_data as (
        SELECT 
            C.ID, 
            replace(replace(replace(replace(C.[Name],',',''),'"',''),':',''),'?','') [Name] ,
            replace(replace(C.[Description],',',''),'"','') [Description],
            C.[GUID],
            C.Businesskey 
        FROM Course C
        JOIN Course_Group CG ON CG.Course_ID = C.ID
        JOIN CourseGroup_CustomerEntitlement CG_CE  ON CG_CE.COURSEGROUP_ID = CG.COURSEGROUP_ID
        JOIN CustomerEntitlement CE_GROUP ON CE_GROUP.ID = CG_CE.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
        AND CE_GROUP.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'CourseGroup'
        WHERE
         CE_GROUP.Customer_ID  = 23753

         UNION
        SELECT 
            C.ID, 
            replace(replace(replace(replace([Name],',',''),'"',''),':',''),'?','') [Name] ,
            replace(replace([Description],',',''),'"','') [Description],
            [GUID],
            Businesskey 
        FROM Course c
        JOIN Course_CustomerEntitlement CCE ON CCE.Course_ID = C.ID 
        JOIN CustomerEntitlement CE_COURSE ON CE_COURSE.ID = CCE.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
        AND CE_COURSE.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'COURSE'
        WHERE
         CE_COURSE.Customer_ID = 23753 

        --and COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  
        --and RETIREDTF = 0  
        --and businesskey in 
        --  (
        --  ...
        --  )
    ),
    CTE_max_data as (
        Select name, max(ID) ID
        from CTE_base_data
        group by name
    )

    Select Data.*
    from CTE_base_data Data
    JOIN CTE_max_data Filter
    ON Data.ID = Filter.ID
    AND Data.Name = Filter.Name
    order by name, id asc
```

This yields:
ID  Name    Description GUID    Businesskey
90000   Contracts      ARB5
40000   NOT Contracts      ARB1

Please advise where my data assumptions fall flat.

Comment: HI, thanks. Actually this database design is not made by me so I can't say anything about this database or table design :). Anyways I run your query. But it is not working as spectating. If i run this query as it is, then i get the error that `Ambiguous column name 'ID'. Ambiguous column name 'Name'.`. If i put `c.ID, c.[Name], c.[GUID], c.Bussinesskey ` and then run the query then I am getting too much rows, with duplicate course name as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I did this. I don't know how efficient this is but it's giving me what I am exactly wanting

```
select ID, [Name], [Description], [GUID], Bussinesskey from (
    select row_number() over (partition by [Name] order by id desc) as row, t1.* from (
        select 
            ID, 
            replace(replace(replace(replace([Name],',',''),'"',''),':',''),'?','') [Name] ,
            replace(replace([Description],',',''),'"','') [Description],
            [GUID],
            Bussinesskey 
        from course 
        where COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and RETIREDTF = 0  
        and bussinesskey in  (
            'PSTOAS0314001',
             ...
            'RECEAL0510019'
        )
        and id in (
            select c.id from course c
            inner join COURSE_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cce on cce.COURSE_ID = c.ID
            inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
            where ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'Course' 
            and ce.customer_id =  23753 
            and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
            UNION 
            select c.id from course c
            inner join COURSE_COURSEGROUP cg on cg.course_id = c.id
            inner join COURSEGROUP_CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT cgce on cgce.COURSEGROUP_ID = cg.COURSEGROUP_ID
            inner join CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT ce on ce.id = cgce.CUSTOMERENTITLEMENT_ID
            where ce.ENROLLMENTTYPE = 'CourseGroup' 
            and ce.customer_id = 23753  
            and c.COURSESTATUS = 'Published'  and c.RETIREDTF = 0
        )
    )t1
) t 
where t.row=1 
order by t.name, t.id asc
```

Thanks